# Performance on a lookup array in C

Tags: c, arrays, performance, lookup

I have to iterate over a log file that contains about 100M lines. I have to do this for multiple logs. The average line length is 110 characters.

Currently I'm looping over a list of possible matches. I would like to know if there's a better way of doing this?

```
char *in_array(char *car) {
    // longer list than this...
    char *carlist[] =
    { 
        "Avalon",
        "Azera",
        "Cayenne",
        "Civic",
        "Corolla",
        "Elantra",
        "F-150",
        "Hilux",
        "Lexus LS",
        "Rav 4",
        "Sienna",
        // etc...
    };  

    char *match;
    int i;
    int n = sizeof(carlist)/sizeof(carlist[0]);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        match = strstr(car, carlist[i]);
        if(match != NULL)
        {
            return strdup(match);
        } 
    }   

    return strdup("No match");
}
```

Comment: You can use `bsearch()`.

Comment: @iharob: `bsearch()` won't work as it's a substring comparison. It's not an array lookup with a given term.

Comment: @iharob Using the bsearch, would I be able to get the the return value from the match and not from the array? e.g., return `Elantra13`, instead of `Elantra`?

Comment: No it is from the array, why are you using `strstr()`? do you want substring match?

Comment: @iharob that's correct, since I don't have the whole list all of possible models for each car.

Comment: For substring matching `bsearch` will not work as commented by `Codo`.

Comment: I assume  that most of the log files are unchanging (archive) while only one or few are changing (the current log). If that is the case you should build an **inverted index** for them and then the search is very fast (or any indexing method)

Comment: That's right, most of the log files do not change. will look into inverted index. Thanks

Comment: @iharob, thanks for pointing a bsearch anyway.

Comment: considered using a database?

Comment: maybe do without the (unnecessary) `strdup`?

Comment: @user1024718 could there be multiple matches?

Comment: @iharob, only one match per line.

Answer (score 5):

A DFA (Deterministic Finite Automaton, plural Automata) can match a string against many patterns much more quickly than sequentially testing each pattern independently.

Parser generators are good at building DFA tables automatically.

The downside is that the DFA has to be rebuilt when the list of patterns changes... but since your list of patterns is currently hardcoded as an array, that shouldn't be problematic for you.

Since you are using C, `flex` would be a good tool to use.

Comment: Can a similar technique be used in languages like `Java/C#` - is there a tutorial one can follow? The question did not interest me but your answer did.

Comment: NB on terminology: `flex` is a scanner generator.  `bison` is the corresponding parser generator.

Comment: @Gene: True.  I suppose that both components of a compiler generator (the scanner/lexer generator and the parser/syntax generator) will use DFA heavily.

Comment: @al-Acme: There is JFlex for Java; I don't know about C#. (Of course, you could just compile the flex function in C and then P/Invoke it.) For a more dynamic approach, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm.

Comment: Sorry about not spelling out the acronym initially.  Good search phrase would be "parallel string matching using DFA"

Comment: @al-Acme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#List_of_lexer_generators and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

Comment: This sounds pretty interesting, I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: @BenVoigt Not really. Normally, scanners are DFAs and parsers are deterministic PDAs. The parser generator `bison` generates LALR and GLR parsers. These are quite different from a simple DFA and not as fast. The power of a PDA parser isn't needed for this problem. The speed of a DFA is.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to improve this brute force search...

1) Parallelism, use OpenCL/CUDA  ( C like languages) and do it on a GPU. Use a GPU thread per keyword. Read parts of the 100M line file into GPU memory and search in parallel. With OpenCL,   that can run on  multi-core H/W  too.

2) Improve the algorithm.  Use a  hash look-up,  compute the CRC32 of the keywords store them in a hash table and compare the  hashed  token from log file records  to entries in the hash table.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of storing the keywords into a hash table.

Comment: This is modeled on a database base hash join of tables

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that the bottleneck in your scan will be the cost of reading the data from the logfiles; almost any non-naive search algorithm should perform faster than a disk seek.

All the same, the brute-force algorithm in the OP is unnecessarily CPU-intensive, particularly if the word-list is long. A reasonably simple and highly-efficient algorithm, for which implementations are readily discoverable, is [Aho-Corasick string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).

If the word-list is static, you could speed that up slightly more by precomputing the transition tables for Aho-Corasick, but in this case, the difference will be negligible compared with the cost of reading the data.

Comment: I imagine this is a more efficient way of building the same DFA as one would get from `flex`... which would definitely be beneficial if the search list could vary at runtime.  On the other hand, it precludes any of the patterns being more complex than a plain string.  Great choice for the particular problem at hand.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's normally a "better" DFA than flex would produce, because unlike the flex-generated scanner, it never has to back up. That would be significant if you expect to find a lot of "false positive" prefixes. (You could generate such a DFA with flex, but you'd basically need to generate the Aho-Corasick machine and then translate it back into a large number of patterns and start conditions; it would get quite messy.) As I said, if the search list is known at compile time, you could pregenerate the machine, which I expect would then be faster than a flex scanner.

Comment: Flex generates scanners that backtrack? I'm gonna have to look for confirmation of that, because DFAs should never backtrack (it's the defining characteristic of DFA vs NFA)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Flex always returns the longest-matching token starting at the current scan point. If some unsuccessful pattern is longer than the longest successful match, then flex has to backup to the end of the longest successful match. If you're searching for keywords, the default rule (which matches a single character) would be the successful match most of the time, so any prefix of a target longer than one character would end up backing up. It never backs up *during a single token scan*, only at the end.

Comment: From the manual: 'Eliminating backtracking among a list of keywords can also be done using a "catch-all" rule:"'  Anyway, since backtracking doesn't occur until after a token is accepted, for the problem at hand it'll never happen, since processing ends on the first match (and restarts with the next haystack).

Comment: @benVoigt: No, it occurs after every many unsuccessful tokens. Suppose you're search for `aaawesome` and the input is `aaaaaaaaaaaawesome`. The first match starts at 0, fails at 3, and matches 0-1 (with the default rule) having inspected four characters. The next one one starts at 1, fails at 4, and matches 1-2. Another four characters. The next one starts at 2, fails at 5, and matches 2-3. So now we've examined 12 characters, and only advanced three characters into the haystack.  And so on, until it finally finds the string. A-C won't do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If flex had some form of non-greediness (which it doesn't), you could build a DFA for `.*?(key1|key2|key3...)`, and then skip to the next line if that failed. Or you could use that DFA even with longest match, but it will always scan the entirely of every line, which is sub-optimal.

Comment: The whole point of using a proper DFA instead of just character-by-character lookup in a trie is so that that doesn't happen.  Maybe flex isn't smart enough, and another scanner generator should be used.  It's true that a scanner that doesn't know the length of the input will waste some time testing the last few characters of input even after no more complete matches are possible.  But your example of `aaaaaaaaawesome` should transition from `aaa` found starting at character 1 to `aaa` found starting at character 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your car names match at the beginning of word, you could parse each line and try to match against the array on each word boundary (using `bsearch()`). That could be faster though you'll need to measure it.

```
static int
compare_car(const void *key, const void *elem)
{
    char *car = (char *)key;
    char *text = * (char **)elem;
    int len = strlen(key);
    return strncmp(car, text, len);
}

char *in_array(char *car) {
    // longer list than this... NEEDS TO BE SORTED
    char *carlist[] =
    { 
        "Avalon",
        "Azera",
        "Cayenne",
        "Civic",
        "Corolla",
        "Elantra",
        "F-150",
        "Hilux",
        "Lexus LS",
        "Rav 4",
        "Sienna",
        // etc...
    };  

    char *match;
    int i;
    int n = sizeof(carlist)/sizeof(carlist[0]);
    int len = strlen(car);
    bool inword = FALSE;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (inword)
        {
            inword = isalnum(car[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (isalnum(car[i]))
            {
                inword = true;
                match = bsearch(car + i, carlist, n, sizeof(char*), compare_car);
                if (match != NULL)
                {
                    return strdup(match);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return strdup("No match");
}
```